# How to check a condition in multiple rows while using group by?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `order_details` (which has `order_id`) and `passenger_via_details` (which has multiple rows with different `status` for each `order_id`). I need to select `order_id` from `passenger_via_details` where the `status` is in `('TB','T')` and not anything else.

I have the following query :

```
SELECT 
    pvd.*
FROM 
     passenger_via_details pvd,
     order_details od 
WHERE 
     pvd.order_id = od.order_id AND pvd.status in ('TB','T') 
GROUP BY order_id;
```

But I get rows which have 'TB','T' and other values as well. How should I change my query to get the desired result?

Comment: Please setup http://sqlfiddle.com/ so we can check you problem

Comment: One of you problems, is that you selecting all column, when grouping just by one of them. In your case you should select only `order_id` and any of aggregate functions(sum, avg and etc.)